# Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, top-7, moderators

**Some guidelines:**

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- The top voted nominations can go forward to the vote.
- The voting will be done on a separate question.

**The candidate:**

- Must be a currently registered user in good standing
- Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
- Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t the same as an obligation. It’s purely voluntary!

Attribution goes to Jeff and ChrisF

More information on how this process will work [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site/58056#58056) and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Comment: 10 days, as good a time as any to get this discussion rolling.

Comment: I find it helpful looking at the Activity tab of a user's Meta profile to see how interested they are in the meta discussion. This kind of discussion will be necessary for any moderator.

Comment: Meta profiles are helpful, and mentioned in the blog. So I added links to the ones that needed it.

Comment: I think there might be some great potential mods who don't come on meta so won't see this thread - how can we let everyone know about this?

Answer (score 6):

I'd nominate [ZorbaTHut](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/323/zorbathut)([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/323/zorbathut)). I don't know him but his answers and comments have been well written and helpful.

Comment: I'll accept the nomination, I don't plan on leaving this site anytime soon :)

Answer (score 6):

Nominating myself: [Tetrad](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/51/tetrad) ([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/tetrad)).

I wasn't a moderator, but very active on the [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/85/tetrad) SE site.

Answer (score 5):

[Munificent](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/160/munificent)([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/160/munificent)) should be a candidate, if he wants it. Oddly, I didn't see his name in Meta, I thought it carried over automatically

Comment: That's very odd, with 159 and 161 being there. Maybe a bug?

Comment: OMG, he's become... *invisible*...

Comment: Looks like only users who visit Meta show up. Right now the user list for meta is 9 pages long but the parent site is 28.

Comment: Well, maybe, if you want to get *technical*, @Colin - personally I prefer the theory that he's developed super-powers. :>

Comment: @Cyclops Maybe that should be a requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, if visiting *Meta* is a requirement, guess that rules him out :(

Comment: According to the [blog post link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) that was just added, Meta involvement is a bonus.

Comment: Extreme Meta involvement is a bonus, but I think he needs to be a little bit active to at least accept his nomination :p

Answer (score 5):

I nominate [Ólafur Waage](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/10/olafur-waage) ([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10/olafur-waage)). Currently the fourth-ranked user, has participated quite a bit on Meta.SO so he clearly knows the system well, *and* he's from Iceland. What more could you want?

Comment: Besides an ice cream sundae, I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Can we nominate ourselves? If so, I'd like to nominate myself: [Sean James](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/353), [Sean James (meta)](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/353)

I participated a lot in the private beta and now in the public beta (#4 in rep at the time of this writing) as well as on our meta. I really like it here so I'm totally up for it. I also have past experience with both website building/moderation from other sites I've worked on as well as experience with community building from my own sites, especially my XNA site [innovativegames.net](http://innovativegames.net).

As far as domain specific knowledge is concerned, I've been building games for years now and programming for longer. While I don't work in the games industry I'd like to in the future. I'm writing a book on XNA due out around October and have a lot of games related stuff on my site linked above.

Answer (score 4):

[Noctrine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/14/noctrine)([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14/noctrine)) seems like a good candidate. He has been involved in the meta site quite a bit, commenting a lot. He also has some good answers on the main site, and a lot of comments there as well.

Comment: Oooo. Well, if the people would have me then I accept.

Answer (score 4):

Nominating [Ben Zeigler](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/162/ben-zeigler)([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/162/ben-zeigler)). He's quite active on the site (currently #4 in reputation) and knows what he's talking about.

In the interests of full disclosure, he's a friend of mine. However, I wouldn't be nominating him if I didn't believe he would do a very good job as a moderator.

Comment: Accepted. I'll be around here for a long time to go.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to nominate [The Communist Duck](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/1156/the-communist-duck) ([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1156/the-communist-duck)), who has done a lot of good work editing and cleaning up questions, and is still active on the site after months.

(Is this still a thing that's happening? A lot of the people suggested here have not been seen in a long time or are not nearly as active as they were, including moderator pro tem Sean James.)

Comment: The non-pro-tem moderators will be voted on using their fancy new server stuff, not a QA thing like we have here.  Example: http://math.stackexchange.com/election

Comment: If I'm being nominated, I would gladly take up the role if the community wants me to. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Going to nominate [David McGraw](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/55/david-mcgraw)([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55/david-mcgraw)). He has beaten me to answering a ton of questions, and usually comes up with solutions that are very well thought out and presented concisely.

Answer (score 2):

If self-nominating is ok (I'll see based on votes!) I'll put my name ([Kevin Bentley](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/204/kevin42)([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/204/kevin42))) out there too.

I've been involved in developing video games for over 20 years, I moderated three round tables at GDC in the late 90s, and have my name in the credits as a developer for several games. I don't work in games any more (although I do military simulation, which has a lot of similarities) but I am actively supporting Descent3 as a hobby, working on a new patch 11 years later!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to nominate myself [Bryan Denny](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/47/bryan-denny) ([meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47/bryan-denny)).

Despite being more of a novice at game dev than a pro, I've been actively contributing (in the top 7) to the site with both questions and answers and hope to be doing so for quite a while as I write my first Android game.

Comment: The contribution is nice, and you have actively driven participation very well with some great questions / answers. The only thing that really prevents me from giving the +1 are those list-questions that while helpful, should really be CW.

Comment: @Noctrine Tetrad did that on a couple for me, feel free to switch any to CW that you feel should be